# pypandoc + pandoc-citeproc to convert bib to rst

Tags: python, pandoc, restructuredtext, bibtex

I have a .bib file with references and I would like to render that file as restructuredtext (in other words, my input is a file references.bib and my desired is file references.rst). That conversion should be done with a Python script, so I tried to use [pypandoc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypandoc) (version 0.9.7, with pandoc version 1.13.1) in combination with the pandoc-citeproc filter.
pypandoc and pandoc are installed correctly, e.g. the following works

```py
import pypandoc
print(pypandoc.get_pandoc_version())
```

My first  idea is to use some kind of nocite* command in a tex or md file and convert that. The (adapted) [example from the pandoc-citeproc issue tracker](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1253) works when used from the command line:

```
pandoc references.tex  -o references.rst --bibliography references.bib
```

But I did not succeed to do the same from python with pypandoc, it is especially unclear to me how to pass extra arguments, e.g. change ibid behavior or specify a [CSL style](http://citationstyles.org/) (changing the biblatex style seems to have no effect).

Also, I do not really like the workaround with the .tex file. 
Can I somehow skip that part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [citeproc-py](https://github.com/brechtm/citeproc-py) for that. You will need to:

1. create a `citeproc.CitationsStyleBibliography`, passing the citation style, a bibtex citation source and a reStructuredText formatter to it;
2. register each element from your bibliographic source;
3. print the bibliography.

You can find examples for these steps in the [examples/](https://github.com/brechtm/citeproc-py/tree/master/examples) directory of `citeproc-py`, or in [bibgen source code](https://github.com/etlapale/bibgen/tree/master). Note that bibgen [allows you](http://emilien.tlapale.com/bibgen/doc/source/rest.html) to directly include a bibliography in a reStructuredText document (including Sphinx sources), see [this example](https://github.com/etlapale/bibgen/raw/master/examples/example-01.rst).